# An issue with Weierstrass theorem's proof (extreme value theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I'm having some issues while I try to understand Weierstrass theorem's proof.

> **Theorem**
> If a real-valued function $f$ is continuous in the closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ must attain a maximum
> and a minimum, each at least once.
>
> **Proof**
> By the boundedness theorem, $f$ is bounded from above, hence, by the Dedekind-completeness of the real numbers, the least
> upper bound (supremum) $M$ of $f$ exists. It is necessary to find a
> $d$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\color{red}{M = f(d)}$. Let $n$ be a natural number. As
> $M$ is the least upper bound, $M – 1/n$ is not an upper bound for $f$.
> Therefore, there exists $d_n$ in $[a,b]$ so that $M – 1/n < f(d_n)$.
> This defines a sequence $\left\{d_n\right\}$. Since $M$ is an upper
> bound for $f$, we have $M – 1/n < f(d_n) ≤ M$ for all $n$. Therefore,
> the sequence $\left\{f(d_n)\right\}$ converges to $M$.
>
> The Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem tells us that there exists a
> subsequence $\left\{d_{n_k}\right\}$, which converges to some $d$ and,
> as $[a,b]$ is closed, $d$ is in $[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous at
> $d$, the sequence $\left\{f(d_{n_k})\right\}$ converges to $f(d)$. But
> $\left\{f(d_{n_k})\right\}$ is a subsequence of
> $\left\{f(d_n)\right\}$ that converges to $M$, so $M = f(d)$.
> Therefore, $f$ attains its supremum $M$ at $d$.
>
> *(excerpted from Wikipedia)*

My book has a similar proof, but it treats separately the cases $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M = +\infty$. But since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ I can't think of an example in which $M$ would equal infinity. Is it really necessary to have two cases like that? If no, what is a simple argument that excludes the case $M \notin \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Perhaps your book hasn't yet proved the "boundedness theorem" and wants to establish that along the way?

Comment: @Hoot: Does the boundedness theorem exclude the case $M = +\infty$? I thought that it said that every continuous function on a closed interval had a supremum, without specifying its nature.

Comment: @rubik: which statement are you referring to? (The one [from Wikipedia, again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) does state the bounds are real.)

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a theorem in that case -- if you allow this $\sup_{x \in [a, b]} f(x)$ to formally be $+\infty$ then you don't need any conditions on $f$ to be able to write $\sup_{x \in [a, b]} f(x)$. I really suspect that the difference between your book and Wikipedia is one of organization of the material.

Comment: Can you give the title of your book ?

Comment: @Hoot: On a closer inspection, I see that as you said earlier, the book establishes the boundedness theorem together with the extreme value theorem and calls it "Weierstrass Theorem". Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: It's a book made by my professor that I don't think is sold outside of the university. The title is "Analisi Matematica I" (Italian for "Calculus I" I think?)

Comment: Anyhow let us know author and university.